# should I mapReduce in mongo or server-side?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

Is there any insights about wether to mapReduce directly on mongoDb, or to get the results and then mapReduce them ?

I want to build some custom query on a few document. Let's say it similar to having a `myArray` value in my documents, that reads

```
myArray: [
  {
    event: 'foo',
    timestamp: 1,
  },  {
    event: 'bar',
    timestamp: 2,
  },  {
    event: 'baz',
    timestamp: 3,
  },
]
```

I want to know the average time there is between `foo` and `bar`.

From what I understand, I can either build a mongo query that will MapReduce my collection and give me the results.

Or I could simply query for the `myArray` keys and mapReduce the results get what I want.

Is there any pro/cons for either of the approaches ?

**[edit]** Note that I'm not asking *how* to write the mapreduce code, rather I'm asking if I should write it database-side or server-side

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried

Comment: Didn't write it yet. I know very well how I could write both of the solutions, but I can't decide if one approach should be better than the other

Comment: Assuming you are using mapReduce because the query is working on a large collection and the output would be a smaller extrapolation of that data why would you want to waste time retrieving all of the documents from the mongo server (also assuming your mongo server is not on the same server) before doing the mapReduce? Even if it is a smallish collection, mongodb is written in C++ and so the mapReduce **might** be more performant over using JavaScript anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side would be faster, but overloading db server with application code is not always wise, and database resources are usally much more expensive than the same on a generic backend machine.

Anyways, faster and also more controlled is the [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/): the right choice if your algorithm fits.